# Rails check if HTTP error code is in 500s

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a sidekiq job which is calling a webservice and it needs to retry if service call fails with HTTP error code in 500s. Is there a standard rails way to check if error code is in 500s ?

Comment: Please post your sidekiq job code, where you call the webservice

Comment: There's no standard way b/c there's no standard HTTP library (there are many of them). Show the code you're using so someone can help.